# Get all responses of the same url in a page using playwright

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, playwright

good day guys,

I want get all the responses of the same url in a page, so that I can merge the responses to process.

[image]

I tried with this code, it gives first response only, but there are ten of the same url request `data/api.json`.

```
 const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(response => {
      response.url().includes('data/api.json') && response.status() === 200
    });
    const response = await responsePromise;
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(await response.allHeaders(), "allheader")
```

Comment: What's the stopping condition? Can you share the actual site so others can provide a working, verified answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign handlers on your requests, using `page.on`.

You can declare an array, then push needed requests to it on event `requestfinished` inside handler, then load the site (or do action that leads to your requests), use `waitForResponse` of first request, wait for some condition when you expect that all requests were received (for example, for requests collection length is not changing along some time interval or network idle).

```js
    const responses: HTTPResponse[] = [];
    const urlPart = 'data/api.json';
    const handler = req => {
      if (req.url().includes(urlPart) && req.response() && req.response().ok()) {
        responses.push(req.response());
      }
    }
    page.on('requestfinished', handler);
    await page.goto("https://yourURL");
    await page.waitForResponse(res => res.request().url().includes(urlPart));
    // propbably there should be another condition where you are sure that no new responses are come
    const jsons = await Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()));
    jsons.forEach(json => console.log(json));
```