# How do I get the URL of a quoted retweet?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Take this tweet (you will have to be logged into twitter to see it): https://twitter.com/JoeBiden/status/1712487592740978801

It quotes this tweet, https://twitter.com/BidenHQ/status/1712485207121465481, which is the URL I'm trying to retrieve.

But when I'm looking into the HTML, there's no `href`, and the URL doesn't appear anywhere. But it must be somewhere? How can I find it? (Except by clicking on the quoted retweet, of course)

In case it's relevant, I'm using `selenium`, here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#launching browser
try:
    chrome_options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=chrome_options)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# connecting to twitter
driver.get("https://twitter.com")

login = "......"
pw = "......"

xpath = '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[5]/a'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()

xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).send_keys(login)

xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()

xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).send_keys(pw)

xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()

# loading the tweet
driver.get("https://twitter.com/JoeBiden/status/1712487592740978801")

# trying to retrieve the URL of the quoted retweet
xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]'

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).no_idea_what_should_go_here_to_get_the_url_of_the_quoted_tweet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to get it via DOM.

This data is present only in response from API which contains url part "TweetDetail".

However, getting that response via Chrome CDP Protocol tools from Selenium is impossible - log entries doesn't contain that request and response (I guess because of bug in Selenium).

But it can be implemented via `Pyppeteer` library - their network interceptor seemed to work fine.

You need to run `pyppeteer` in async mode, perform login, open new tab and open your link.

Then you wait for response which contain `TweetDetail` and get `quoted_status_permalink` deep inside.

That is example of implementation that gets your link from response object.

You can play with it and probably find way how to do that via Selenium / `requests` lib, etc.

```py
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()

    login = ''
    pw = ''

    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/i/flow/login')
    username = await page.waitForSelector('input[autocomplete=username]')
    await username.type(login)

    await page.click('[role=button].r-13qz1uu')

    password = await page.waitForSelector('[type=password]')
    await password.type(pw)

    login_button = await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid*=Login_Button]')
    await login_button.click()
    await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid=AppTabBar_DirectMessage_Link]')

    url = 'https://twitter.com/JoeBiden/status/1712487592740978801'
    target_url = 'TweetDetail'
    tweet_page = await browser.newPage()
    await tweet_page.goto(url)
    res = await tweet_page.waitForResponse(lambda req: target_url in req.url)
    res_json = await res.json()
    target_entry_id = url.split('status/')[1]
    entries = res_json.get('data')['threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2']['instructions'][0]['entries']
    current_tweet = None
    for i in range(len(entries)):
        if target_entry_id in entries[i]['entryId']:
            current_tweet = entries[i]
            break
    retweet_link = current_tweet['content']['itemContent']['tweet_results']['result']['legacy']['quoted_status_permalink']['expanded']
    print(retweet_link)
    await browser.close()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Example of code if you want to get several tweet details by scrolling down (be aware, that results from not main tweet have different JSON structure, so it may be case dependant, probably, you should analyse responses to define correct path)

```py
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def process():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()

    login = ''
    pw = ''

    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/i/flow/login')
    username = await page.waitForSelector('input[autocomplete=username]')
    await username.type(login)

    await page.click('[role=button].r-13qz1uu')

    password = await page.waitForSelector('[type=password]')
    await password.type(pw)

    login_button = await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid*=Login_Button]')
    await login_button.click()
    await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid=AppTabBar_DirectMessage_Link]')

    url = 'https://twitter.com/JoeBiden/status/1712487592740978801'
    target_url = 'TweetDetail'
    tweet_page = await browser.newPage()
    responses = []

    def request_finished_handler(request):
        request_url = request.url
        if target_url in request_url:
            responses.append(request.response)

    tweet_page.on('requestfinished', request_finished_handler)
    await tweet_page.goto(url)
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # there should be your scroll except this wait
    await tweet_page.waitForResponse(lambda req: target_url in req.url)
    for res in responses:
        res_json = await res.json()
        entries = res_json.get('data')['threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2']['instructions'][0]['entries']
        for i in range(len(entries)):
            entry = entries[i]
            try:
                if 'tweet' in entry['entryId']:
                    content = entry['content']['itemContent']
                else: # JSON structure for conversation is different
                    content = entry['content']['items'][0]['item']['itemContent']
                legacy = content['tweet_results']['result']['legacy']
                permalink = legacy['quoted_status_permalink']
                if permalink:
                    print(permalink['expanded'])
            except Exception:
                continue
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(process())
```

[image: Request in dev tools]

[image: Response]

Comment: Thank you. First time dealing with async/await so I don't know what I'm doing... I get a `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` error when running your code.

Comment: Try to close the browser (I added in snippet code that closes this after launch).

Also, you can try to use instead of `asyncio.get_event_loop` if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Comment: https://www.zenrows.com/blog/pyppeteer#parse-html - here is example how to work with `pyppeteer` (there are lots of resources).

Comment: I found what's causing the problem: I'm using Spyder (solution for anyone who would read this in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156310/4348534)

Comment: Glad to hear. IMO `pyppeteer` is better than Selenium for your case, it's better when you need to deal with frontend UI + intercept requests.

Comment: Yeah, it seems much more straightforward. It's just that I'll have to not mess up the async/await thing... Code works flawlessly by the way, thanks! Now I have to understand it.

Comment: Can you explain the `await tweet_page.waitForResponse(lambda req: target_url in req.url)` line please? If I get i right, it's waiting for a network resource (not sure how to call it) that has `TweetDetail` in its name. But what if (in another use case) there are multiple resources that have `TweetDetail` in its name? How can make it so `res` has not the first one only, but every instance of the resources?

Comment: Correct. It is waiting for first response for defined url part. If there are several same responses, you can use approach with `page.on`. I explained how to do it in JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77027553/get-all-responses-of-the-same-url-in-a-page-using-playwright/77027995#77027995 (Pyppeteer came from JS Puppeteer), in Python it would be similar.

Comment: LMK if you need to rewrite code from above from JS to Python

Comment: handler variable there is anonymous function (lambda in Python) that is passed inside page.on

Comment: Yes please, I'm trying but I can't get it right...

Comment: @FrançoisM. can you provide a link where I can find several requests in order to test solution?

Comment: Well I'm on any twitter profile, and scrolling with `await page.evaluate("""{window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);}""")` which spawns multiple `UserTweets` requests

Comment: @FrançoisM. spent ~ 1 hour with dealing different JSON structure from conversations below tweet on scrolling. Probably you need to analyse structure for each case by your own - it can be different. Look at my second snippet. But in any case you have the point from which you can start. There an example, how to work with `page.on`. The bottleneck in your case is to parse response JSON correctly.

Comment: Yes I can handle the JSON parsing. I just needed the `request_finished_handler()`. Thank you very much!